# Could not cast value of type 'UIBarButtonItem' to 'UITableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

Has anyone encounter the below error?
I am trying to navigate from a uitableviewcontroller to a uiviewcontroller.
The uitableviewcontroller is using NSFetchedResultsController.
The Application is breaking in the segue to the uiviewcontroller (named: TaskDetailViewController)

[**Repo with Complete Code**](https://github.com/LuAndreCast/Swift_Projects/tree/master/Core%20Data/Task%20Manager)

**Error:** Could not cast value of type 'UIBarButtonItem' (0x1a0d22b50) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x1a0d224c0).
(lldb)

**Storyboard:**
[image: storyBoard]

[Repo with Complete Code](https://github.com/LuAndreCast/Swift_Projects/tree/master/Core%20Data/Task%20Manager)

**Code where App Breaks:**

```
    if segue.identifier == "editTask"
    {
        let cell        = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath   = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

        let taskController:TaskDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TaskDetailViewController

        let task:Tasks = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Tasks
        taskController.task = task
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line: `let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell`. In this case, it appears that your segue is being performed when the user presses a `UIBarButtonItem`. So your sender is a `UIBarButtonItem`, not a `UITableViewCell`. This means that the forced cast (as!) from `sender` (`UIBarButtonItem`) to a `UITableViewCell` will cause a crash.

Comment: How can I fix this? My goal is to know the total number of cells to pass to the fetchedResultsController

Comment: You may just need to change it so that your segue is triggered when the user selects the `UITableViewCell` instead of when they tap the `UIBarButtonItem`. Use a different segue when they tap on the `UIBarButtonItem`. There are other things you could potentially do to fix this, but that may be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I guees you added segue to button instead of cell.